# I am trying to create a login page that goes to a home page on an app, but the button will not click at all, it's like a wall. I have

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, authentication

I am a very new coder trying to build my first app. I have created a login page but something seems to be blocking it. I am not sure why it is not working, could it be a small error or something else?  My sign-up page works fine but the login does not even click through. Can anyone help find what might be the error in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: content: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <!-- CSP, above, is used to set what resources the app can access -->
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <!-- Required Monaca stuff above, do not edit -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycolors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  
     <!-- START Welcome screen -->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="pgWelcome">        
 
 <!-- Main content in the middle of the screen -->
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h2>CBDB -- Comic Book Database</h2>    
         
         <p><img src="images/usg-14.png" alt="usg-14" class="imgMain"></p>
         <p>Collect, store, save, and share your comics in one place. Learn all about the great world of comics.</p>
         <p>Need an account? <a href="#pgSignUp" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="star">Create an account</a></p>
         <p>Have an account?<a href="#pgLogin" data-role="button" data-transition="fli" data-icon="star">Log In</a></p>
     </article>
 <!-- JS content at the bottom of the screen -->
    
 </section>
 <!-- END Welcome screen -->
 <!-- START SignUp screen-->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="pgSignUp">
     <header data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
         <h1>Sign Up</h1>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <!-- A <form> element to ask for credentials for creating an account 1:09-->
         <form id="fmSignUp">
             <label for="inEmailSignUp">Email:</label>
             <input name="inEmailSignUp" type="email" placeholder="loislane@dailyplanet.com" required id="inEmailSignUp">
             <label for="inPasswordSignUp">Password:</label>
             <input name="inPasswordSignUp" type="password" placeholder="girlreporter222" required id="inPasswordSignUp">
             <label for="inPasswordConfirmSignUp">Confirm Password:</label>
             <input name="inPasswordConfirmSignUp" type="password" placeholder="girlreporter222" required id="inPasswordConfirmSignUp">
             <!-- Grid with two columns, get code from jQueryMobile -->
             <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                 <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="reset" value="Clear"></div>
                 <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit" value="Go"></div>
             </fieldset>
         </form>
     </article>
 </section>
 <!-- END SignUp screen-->
 <!-- START LogIn screen -->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pgLogIn">
    <header data-role="header" data-transition="flip" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>Log In!</h1>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <form id="fmLogIn">
             <label for="inEmailLogIn">Email:</label>
             <input name="inEmailLogIn" type="email" placeholder="loislane@dailyplanet.com" required id="inEmailLogIn">
             <label for="inPasswordLogIn">Password:</label>
             <input name="inPasswordLogIn" type="password" placeholder="girlreporter222" required id="inPasswordLogIn">
             <!-- Grid with two columns in a form. Note FIELDSET -- which is used in a form (if it's not in a form, use DIV) -->
             <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                 <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="reset" data-icon="delete" value="Clear"></div>
                 <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit" data-icon="forward" value="Go"></div>
             </fieldset>       
         </form>
        <!-- <a href="#pgHome" data-transition="flip">Go to Home</a> -->
     </article>    
 </section>    
 <!-- END Login screen-->
   
 <!-- START Home screen-->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="pgHome">
     <header data-role="header">
        <h1>CBDB</h1>
         <a href="#pgOptions" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop">Options</a>
        
             <nav data-role="navbar">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#pgHome" data-transition="pop" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgSave" data-transition="pop" data-icon="action">Save</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgView" data-transition="pop" data-icon="bars">View</a></li>  
                 </ul>
             </nav>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h2>Home</h2>
         <img src="images/promotiger1.png" alt="promotiger1" class="imgHome">
         <h4>The fun way to find your comics all in one place! Join the fun in collecting and sharing comics. Invite your friends!</h4>
         <a href="#pgWelcome" data-transition="flip">Go to Welcome</a>
     </article>
     <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h4>Copyright 2021 -- Monica Showalter Productions</h4>
     </footer>
 </section>
 <!-- END Home screen -->
 <!-- START Save screen -->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pgSave">
     <header data-role="header">
         <h1>Save your Comic</h1>
         <a href="#pgOptions" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop">Options</a>
             <nav data-role="navbar">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#pgHome" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgSave" data-icon="action" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Save</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgView" data-icon="bars">View</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </nav>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <!-- <form> to save inventory to database -->
             <form id="fmSaveComic">
                 <!-- Set up optional and required data to save -->
                 <fieldset>
                     <legend>Required</legend>
                         <label for="inTitleSave">Title: </label>
                             <input name="inTitleSave" type="text" required placeholder="Kimba the White Lion" id="inTitleSave">
                         <label for="inNumberSave">Number: </label>
                             <input name="inNumberSave" type="number" required placeholder="15" id="inNumberSave">
                         <label for="inYearSave">Year: </label>
                             <input name="inYearSave" type="number" required placeholder="1969" id="inYearSave">
                 </fieldset>
                 <fieldset>
                     <legend>Optional</legend>
                         <label for="inPublisherSave">Publisher: </label>
                         <input name="inPublisherSave" type="text" placeholder="Mushi Production" id="inPublisherSave">
                         <label for="inNotesSave">Notes: </label>
                         <textarea name="inNotesSave" placeholder="First published in Japan" id="inNotesSave"></textarea>
                 </fieldset>
                 <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                         <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="reset" data-icon="delete" value="Cancel"></div>
                         <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit" data-icon="forward" value="Save"></div>
                 </fieldset>                   
                 <!--Three column grid with setup button is below, I used 'submit' input type to keep it consistent with other buttons. This was from the assignment l
(buttons for setup, cancel and save), but the lecture suggested a more classic two-column style on 'save' page was expected so perhaps 'set-up' meant
worked fine in this form below and looked good, but I went with the class demo in code above. However, I include in this submission that I learned ho
columns, too -->
                <!-- <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
                     <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="submit" data-icon="check" value="Set Up"></div>
                     <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="reset" data-icon="delete" value="Cancel"></div>
                     <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="submit" data-icon="forward" value="Save"></div>
                 </fieldset> -->                   
             </form>
     <a href="#pgView" data-role="button" data-transition="pop" data-icon="action">Go to View</a>
     </article>
     <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h4>Copyright 2021 -- Monica Showalter Productions</h4>
     </footer>
 </section>
 <!-- End SAVE screen -->
 <!-- Start VIEW screen -->
 <section data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pgView">
     <header data-role="header">
         <h1>View Your Comic</h1>
         <a href="#pgOptions" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop">Options</a>
             <nav data-role="navbar">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#pgHome" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgSave" data-icon="action">Save</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#pgView" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">View</a></li>  
                 </ul>
             </nav>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h2>Take a look at your comic in living color!</h2>
         <a href="#pgHome" data-role="button" data-transition="pop" data-icon="home" >View</a>
     </article>
     <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h4>Copyright 2021 -- Monica Showalter Productions</h4>
     </footer>
 </section>
 <!-- End VIEW screen -->
 <!-- Start OPTIONS screen -->
 <section data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-theme="c" id="pgOptions">
     <header data-role="header">
         <h1>Options</h1>
     </header>
     <article role="main" class="ui-content">
         <p>A mobile app for comic book storage created by Monica Showalter in 2021. Copyright Monica Showalter Productions.</p>
         <!-- Current button is a simple button but will be JavaScript eventually. Add an ID for that-->
         <p><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="power" data-transition="pop" id="btnLogOut"></a>Log Out</p>
         Contact Us | Reset Account
     </article>
 </section>
 <!-- End OPTIONS screen -->
 <!-- JavaScript should be before </body -->
 <!-- Links to the online JS files-->
    
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Javascript page:

// Before any of our JavaScript can function, it should be in a "device ready" function
// that Cordova detected all foundational elements have been loaded
// Listen for the moment all your files load into memory
// Then run the main function "onDeviceReady ()"

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// All future JS code must be on the onDeviceReady main function
function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log("Cordova is ready!");

// ---- Variables ----
// These are containers for data
// Create variables for SignUp/LogIn forms, LogOut button
// var classic way, works
// let newer way, recommended for creating Object that varies
// const newer way, recommended for creating Object that does not vary
// document.getElementByID("fmSignUp") -- means find an HTML element with that ID, pJS or plain JS way
// $("#fmSignUp") --- means same thing as above, jQuery way

const $elFmSignUp = $("#fmSignUp"), // el means 'element' of HTML. Also, use $ for const name to remind it's in jquery, as seen
      $elFmLogIn = $("#fmLogIn"), // This section tells JS where to find the form so it can interact
      $elBtnLogOut = $("#btnLogOut");

// ---- Functions ----
// These are the subroutines (bundles of code) that accomplish a task
// Create a function to do all the steps signing up for an account
function fnSignUp(event) {
  // prevent default event of refresh
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("fnSignUp(event) is running!");
let $elInEmailSignUp = $("#inEmailSignUp"),
    $elInPasswordSignUp = $("#inPasswordSignUp"),
    $elInPasswordConfirmSignUp = $("#inPasswordConfirmSignUp");
// Quick test to read what's in box
console.log($elInEmailSignUp.val(), $elInPasswordSignUp.val(), $elInPasswordConfirmSignUp.val());
//next slide's code goes here because we will nest objects in the function
//this is to confirm passwords match
if($elInPasswordSignUp.val() != $elInPasswordConfirmSignUp.val()) {
  console.log("Passwords do not match!");
  window.alert("Passwords do not match!");
  //$elInPasswordSignUp.val(""); /* blanking these two lines out as don't match instructor code */
  //$elInPasswordConfirmSignUp.val(""); 
} else { 
  console.log ("Passwords DO match!");
// next slide's code goes here
// Now using local storage to save User data as new account:
let $tmpValInEmailSignUp = $elInEmailSignUp.val().toUpperCase(),
    $tmpValInPasswordSignUp = $elInPasswordSignUp.val();

if(localStorage.getItem($tmpValInEmailSignUp) === null) {
  console.log("New User detected!");
  // Now we store the new User
  localStorage.setItem($tmpValInEmailSignUp, $tmpValInPasswordSignUp);
  // Clear for the next User
  $elFmSignUp[0].reset();
  // Welcome the new User
  window.alert("Welcome!");
  console.log("New User saved" + $tmpValInEmailSignUp);
} else { 
  window.alert("You already have an account!");
    } // END If..Else for new/old user check

  } // END If..Else for Password matching

} // END fnSignUp(event)

function fnLogIn() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("fnLogIn() is running!"); // adjusted this to match instructor code, had word 'event' in the function ()

  let $elInEmailLogIn = $("#inEmailLogIn"),
      $elInPasswordLogIn = $("#inPasswordLogIn"),
      $tmpValInEmailLogIn = $elInEmailLogIn.val().toUpperCase(), // added function parens toUpperCase to match instructor code
      $tmpValInPasswordLogIn = $elInPasswordLogIn.val();

  console.log($tmpValInEmailLogIn, $tmpValInPasswordLogIn);

// Conditional statement to see if account was previously created
  if (localStorage.getItem($tmpValInEmailLogIn) === null) {
    console.log("Account does not exist.");
    window.alert("Account does not exist!");
  } else {
    console.log("Account does exist.");

    if ($tmpValInPasswordLogIn === localStorage.getItem($tmpValInEmailLogIn)) {
      console.log("Passwords DO match!");
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#pgHome");
    } else {
      console.log("Passwords do not match.");
      window.alert("WRONG password!");
     } // END If..Else checking for password match *** CHECK THIS AGAIN, ADDED MYSELF
  } // END If..Else checking for user account existence
} // END fnLogIn()

// Function to log out the User

function fnLogOut() {
  console.log("fnLogOut() is running");

  //Conditional Statement to confirm whether they really intend to log out
switch(window.confirm("Do you want to log out?")) {
  case true:
    console.log("User does want to log out");
    // Move them to #pgWelcome
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#pgWelcome");
    // Now clear the <form> for a new User
    $elFmSignUp[0].reset();
    $elFmLogIn[0].reset();
    break;
    case false:
    console.log("User does not want to log out");
    break;
    case "Maybe":
    console.log("User might want to log out");
    break;
    default:
    console.log("Unknown");
    break;
  } // END switch() to log out
} // END FnLogOut() 

// ---- Event Listeners ----
// These are detecting interaction
// Wait for "submit" button in the FmSignUp <form>
// Then run a function called fnSignUp(), capture the default event, pass it through
$elFmSignUp.submit(function(){  fnSignUp(event);  });
$elFmLogIn.submit(function(){  fnLogIn(); });
$elBtnLogOut.on("click", fnLogOut);

} // End onDeviceReady()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my mind ,the question is occur because of the spell of line 30:

```html
<p>Have an account?<a href="#pgLogin" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="star">Log In</a></p>
```

and the reference line 61:

```html
<section data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="pgLogIn">
```

as you can see, the `pgLogin` not equals with `pgLogIn`, change them to equals will resolve the question

Comment: OMG it works! That one was indeed missed. I corrected it and for the first time it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check your login function, in the javascript it doesn't have event while in the signup it has an event in it's argument. This may help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much, i will look at this next.